# Describe a computation

Tags: scala, functional-programming, io-monad

I have the following code, that I would like to know, why the variable `number` gets evaluated twice:

```
import cats.effect.IO

import scala.util.Random

object Main {

  private val number: IO[Int] =
    IO(Random.between(3, 300))

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {


    number
      .flatMap { e =>
        println(e);
        number
      }.flatMap { e =>
      println(e);
      IO.unit
    }.unsafeRunSync()
  }

}
```

the program prints two different numbers, although the number is an assignment. I know here, I describe a computation not a execution, and at the end of the universe, I run the program.

The question is, why it prints out two different numbers?

Comment: I cannot find [`Random.between`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/util/Random.html).

Comment: Note, if it would have returned the same value, it would have broken **referential transparency** which is the only reason to introduce `IO` in the first place. Also, your _prints_ are wrong, all effects must be suspended inside an `IO`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a difference between

```
private val number: IO[Int] = IO(Random.nextInt())
```

and

```
private val number2: Int = Random.nextInt()
```

`number` is a value that when evaluated computes a random number. When evaluated multiple times this value of type `IO` (aka this computation) is run multiple times resulting in multiple different random numbers.

Whereas `number2` when evaluated is just a single number.

It is very similar to the distinction between a lambda (`val lambda = () => Random.nextInt()`) and a value (`val value = Random.nextInt()`).

Comment: What is the different between computation and evaluation?

Comment: Let's use *evaluation* for replacing an expression with its value. Let's use *computation* as a general name for values of type `IO`, as in *strings* are values of type `String`.

Answer (score 2):

`IO` is a bit similar to the following scenario

```
final case class SuspendedComputation[T](f: () => T) {
  def run: T = f()
}

val v = SuspendedComputation(Random.nextInt)
v.run
v.run
```

which outputs something like

```
v: SuspendedComputation[Int] = SuspendedComputation(<function>
res2: Int = -1062309211
res3: Int = 765640585
```

Note how `SuspendedComputation` internally stores computation as `() => Random.nextInt` and then uses `run` method to actually evaluate computation `f`.

Similarly, [`IO.apply`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/blob/78d19ca2fc9ac462e0cd938cfd5ff4cac49281ea/core/shared/src/main/scala/cats/effect/IO.scala#L1006) accepts an argument by-name `: => A` and eventually constructs [`Delay`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/blob/78d19ca2fc9ac462e0cd938cfd5ff4cac49281ea/core/shared/src/main/scala/cats/effect/IO.scala#L1444) object that stores the un-evaluated computation in a field as `() => A` and then uses `unsafeRunSync` to actually evaluate computation.